# Binding in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

For the life of me I can't get this binding to work.

On the top is my attempt, on the bottom is an example I found online, which works.

```xml
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" Width="200" Background="White">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="shortcutsItems" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            Hello world
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Normal text"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ListView x:Name="shortcutsList" Width="100">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridShortcuts">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

```cs
    public partial class ExamShortcuts : UserControl {
        public ExamShortcuts() {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<Shortcut> shortcuts = new ObservableCollection<Shortcut>();

            shortcuts = new ObservableCollection<Shortcut>();
            shortcutsList.ItemsSource = shortcuts;
            shortcutsItems.ItemsSource = shortcuts;  // ERROR!!!

            //shortcuts.Add(new Shortcut() { Name = "Shortcut Exam 1" });
            //shortcuts.Add(new Shortcut() { Name = "Shortcut Exam 2" });
        }
    }

    public class Shortcut {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run, it says "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource" for `shortcutsItems.ItemsSource = shortcuts;`
Note that is IS EMPTY!!!!! And of course it doesn't work when the `Add` lines are uncommented, either.
I've tried using `DataContext = shortcuts` and `ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding]"` with the same result.

Also, all examples I've seen have the `ItemSource` assignment in the code after the items are added anyway!

The `shortcutsList` works fine.

Comment: _"Note that is IS EMPTY!!!!!"_ -- you can put as many exclamation marks as you like, that doesn't change the fact that the collection is _not_ empty, and that you would never see that exception if it were. Debugging the code would've revealed to yourself what was going on.

Comment: Debugging with the debugger? It would be nice for you to have explained in what way it was not empty. I did know the "Hello World" was there but I obviously didn't understand that it "counted" as the source. I was going off of `shortcuts` being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "Hello World" and the ItemSource binding parts prior to setting the `ItemsSource` in your codebehind. You are trying to set it dynamically, but have already set it in your xaml which is why it think's the source is not empty. I bet that's causing your issue.

Change

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="shortcutsItems" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     Hello world
```

to

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="shortcutsItems" Width="100">
```

Comment: Oh my god I hate myself. I definitely tried this several times before inserting the Hello World but something in between must have changed that would have worked if it weren't there. Thank you.

Comment: Such is the life of programming haha, we all go there daily! Glad it worked.